# PySpark returns an exception when I try to cast string columns as numeric

Tags: casting, pyspark, python-3.6, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to cast string columns to numeric, but I am getting an exception in PySpark.  I provide below the code and the error message.

Is it possible to import the specific columns from the csv file as numeric? (the default is to be imported as strings).

What are my alternative?

My code and the error messages follow below:

```
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

import findspark

findspark.init()

import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Loads data. Be careful of indentations and whitespace
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master('local') \
.appName('Data cleaning') \
.getOrCreate()

# These lines enable the run of spark commands

from pyspark.context import SparkContext
#from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

#spark = SparkSession(sc)

import os
os.chdir('D:\\DIGITAL_LIBRARY\\DataCamp')

df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').option('mode','DROPMALFORMED').\
load('D:\DIGITAL_LIBRARY\DataCamp\\df.csv')

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.columns
['sku_id',
 'promo_start_week',
 'hierarchy2_name',
 'brand',
 'region',
 'store_norm_group',
 'holiday_names',
 'holiday_types',
 'list_price_net_q0.7',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.7',
 'list_price_net_q0.3_relative',
 'discount_rate',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.9',
 'list_price_net_q0.3',
 'list_price_net_q0.7_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative',
 'promoted_price_net',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative',
 'list_price_net_q0.1',
 'list_price_net_q0.5_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.5',
 'list_price_net_q0.5',
 'revenue',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.3',
 'list_price_net_q0.9',
 'list_price_net_q0.1_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative',
 'First_week_of_promo',
 'list_price_net_q0.9_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.1']

cols_to_numeric = ['list_price_net_q0.7',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.7',
 'list_price_net_q0.3_relative',
 'discount_rate',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.9',
 'list_price_net_q0.3',
 'list_price_net_q0.7_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative',
 'promoted_price_net',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative',
 'list_price_net_q0.1',
 'list_price_net_q0.5_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.5',
 'list_price_net_q0.5',
 'revenue',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.3',
 'list_price_net_q0.9',
 'list_price_net_q0.1_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative',
 'First_week_of_promo',
 'list_price_net_q0.9_relative',
 'promoted_price_net_q0.1']

df1 = df.select(*(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in cols_to_numeric))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

D:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`list_price_net_q0.7`' given input columns: [promoted_price_net_q0.1, promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative, promo_start_week, promoted_price_net_q0.9, discount_rate, promoted_price_net, brand, holiday_names, list_price_net_q0.1, list_price_net_q0.7_relative, revenue, promoted_price_net_q0.7, First_week_of_promo, promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative, promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative, promoted_price_net_q0.5, list_price_net_q0.5, promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative, sku_id, promoted_price_net_q0.3, list_price_net_q0.3, list_price_net_q0.1_relative, hierarchy2_name, store_norm_group, list_price_net_q0.5_relative, list_price_net_q0.9_relative, region, promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative, list_price_net_q0.9, holiday_types, list_price_net_q0.7, list_price_net_q0.3_relative];;
'Project [cast('list_price_net_q0.7 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.7#109, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.7 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.7#110, cast('list_price_net_q0.3_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.3_relative#111, cast(discount_rate#22 as float) AS discount_rate#112, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.9 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.9#113, cast('list_price_net_q0.3 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.3#114, cast('list_price_net_q0.7_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.7_relative#115, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative#116, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative#117, cast(promoted_price_net#28 as float) AS promoted_price_net#118, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative#119, cast('list_price_net_q0.1 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.1#120, cast('list_price_net_q0.5_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.5_relative#121, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative#122, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.5 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.5#123, cast('list_price_net_q0.5 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.5#124, cast(revenue#35 as float) AS revenue#125, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.3 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.3#126, cast('list_price_net_q0.9 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.9#127, cast('list_price_net_q0.1_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.1_relative#128, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative#129, cast(First_week_of_promo#40 as float) AS First_week_of_promo#130, cast('list_price_net_q0.9_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.9_relative#131, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.1 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.1#132]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [sku_id#11, promo_start_week#12, hierarchy2_name#13, brand#14, region#15, store_norm_group#16, holiday_names#17, holiday_types#18, list_price_net_q0.7#19, promoted_price_net_q0.7#20, list_price_net_q0.3_relative#21, discount_rate#22, promoted_price_net_q0.9#23, list_price_net_q0.3#24, list_price_net_q0.7_relative#25, promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative#26, promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative#27, promoted_price_net#28, promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative#29, list_price_net_q0.1#30, list_price_net_q0.5_relative#31, promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative#32, promoted_price_net_q0.5#33, list_price_net_q0.5#34, ... 8 more fields]
         +- Relation[_c0#10,sku_id#11,promo_start_week#12,hierarchy2_name#13,brand#14,region#15,store_norm_group#16,holiday_names#17,holiday_types#18,list_price_net_q0.7#19,promoted_price_net_q0.7#20,list_price_net_q0.3_relative#21,discount_rate#22,promoted_price_net_q0.9#23,list_price_net_q0.3#24,list_price_net_q0.7_relative#25,promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative#26,promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative#27,promoted_price_net#28,promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative#29,list_price_net_q0.1#30,list_price_net_q0.5_relative#31,promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative#32,promoted_price_net_q0.5#33,... 9 more fields] csv

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:3295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f7e0007723d8> in <module>()
----> 1 df1 = df.select(*(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in cols_to_numeric))

D:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in select(self, *cols)
   1200         [Row(name=u'Alice', age=12), Row(name=u'Bob', age=15)]
   1201         """
-> 1202         jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
   1203         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
   1204 

D:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

D:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`list_price_net_q0.7`' given input columns: [promoted_price_net_q0.1, promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative, promo_start_week, promoted_price_net_q0.9, discount_rate, promoted_price_net, brand, holiday_names, list_price_net_q0.1, list_price_net_q0.7_relative, revenue, promoted_price_net_q0.7, First_week_of_promo, promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative, promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative, promoted_price_net_q0.5, list_price_net_q0.5, promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative, sku_id, promoted_price_net_q0.3, list_price_net_q0.3, list_price_net_q0.1_relative, hierarchy2_name, store_norm_group, list_price_net_q0.5_relative, list_price_net_q0.9_relative, region, promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative, list_price_net_q0.9, holiday_types, list_price_net_q0.7, list_price_net_q0.3_relative];;\n'Project [cast('list_price_net_q0.7 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.7#109, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.7 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.7#110, cast('list_price_net_q0.3_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.3_relative#111, cast(discount_rate#22 as float) AS discount_rate#112, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.9 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.9#113, cast('list_price_net_q0.3 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.3#114, cast('list_price_net_q0.7_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.7_relative#115, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative#116, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative#117, cast(promoted_price_net#28 as float) AS promoted_price_net#118, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative#119, cast('list_price_net_q0.1 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.1#120, cast('list_price_net_q0.5_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.5_relative#121, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative#122, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.5 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.5#123, cast('list_price_net_q0.5 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.5#124, cast(revenue#35 as float) AS revenue#125, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.3 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.3#126, cast('list_price_net_q0.9 as float) AS list_price_net_q0.9#127, cast('list_price_net_q0.1_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.1_relative#128, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.9_relative#129, cast(First_week_of_promo#40 as float) AS First_week_of_promo#130, cast('list_price_net_q0.9_relative as float) AS list_price_net_q0.9_relative#131, cast('promoted_price_net_q0.1 as float) AS promoted_price_net_q0.1#132]\n+- AnalysisBarrier\n      +- Project [sku_id#11, promo_start_week#12, hierarchy2_name#13, brand#14, region#15, store_norm_group#16, holiday_names#17, holiday_types#18, list_price_net_q0.7#19, promoted_price_net_q0.7#20, list_price_net_q0.3_relative#21, discount_rate#22, promoted_price_net_q0.9#23, list_price_net_q0.3#24, list_price_net_q0.7_relative#25, promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative#26, promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative#27, promoted_price_net#28, promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative#29, list_price_net_q0.1#30, list_price_net_q0.5_relative#31, promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative#32, promoted_price_net_q0.5#33, list_price_net_q0.5#34, ... 8 more fields]\n         +- Relation[_c0#10,sku_id#11,promo_start_week#12,hierarchy2_name#13,brand#14,region#15,store_norm_group#16,holiday_names#17,holiday_types#18,list_price_net_q0.7#19,promoted_price_net_q0.7#20,list_price_net_q0.3_relative#21,discount_rate#22,promoted_price_net_q0.9#23,list_price_net_q0.3#24,list_price_net_q0.7_relative#25,promoted_price_net_q0.5_relative#26,promoted_price_net_q0.7_relative#27,promoted_price_net#28,promoted_price_net_q0.1_relative#29,list_price_net_q0.1#30,list_price_net_q0.5_relative#31,promoted_price_net_q0.3_relative#32,promoted_price_net_q0.5#33,... 9 more fields] csv\n"
```

A similar error is produced when I try:

```
df = df.withColumn('list_price_net_q0.7', col('list_price_net_q0.7').cast('float'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark cannot resolve column names with dots  due to a bug (see this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12965) for more information). Just use the code below to clean up your column names:

```
columns = ['id', 'list_price_net_q0.7', 'bla']
vals = [(1.0, '2.0', 0),(2.0, '3.0', 1)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df.printSchema()
#actual clean up
x = [s.replace('.', 'DOT') for s in df.columns]
df = df.toDF(*x)
#prove that you can cast now
df.withColumn("float", col("list_price_net_q0DOT7").cast("float")).show()
```

Another option is to set the [inferSchema](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) parameter to True. This will probably create a dataframe where 'list_price_net_q0.7' is a column of floats, but as soon as you apply another function you will stumple upon the same bug.