# pyspark cannot resolve '`col.name`' given input columns: [col.name] - dot in col name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Spark version version 2.4.5

```py
>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col

>> data = [('a',),
        ('b',)]

>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("col.name",))

>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col.name: string (nullable = true)
```

Execution of this line

```
>> df.withColumn("col.name.new",col("col.name")).show()
```

give this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1187.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`col.name`' given input columns: [col.name]
```

but this works

```
>> df.withColumn("col.name.new",col("`col.name`")).show()
+--------+------------+
|col.name|col.name.new|
+--------+------------+
|       a|           a|
|       b|           b|
+--------+------------+
```

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col)

> pyspark.sql.functions.col(col)
> Returns a Column based on the given column name.

The first attempt should work.

Do you know why it does not?

Comment: I can't flag it as duplicate, but I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54381106/pyspark-returns-an-exception-when-i-try-to-cast-string-columns-as-numeric/54383322#54383322). It is caused by a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19416).

Comment: Thank you @cronoik, do you know if this is also valid for spark>=3.0.0?

Comment: Well according to the bug report it should not be the case, but I have not tested it.

Comment: I check and for spark==3.0.1 this is still a bug.

Comment: Good to know. That means you should still avoid column names with dots or replace them.

Answer (score 0):

It will make sense if we look at fields with `struct` type ([StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType)).

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
>>> data = [('a','{"name":1}'),
...         ('b','{"name":2}')]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("col.name","col"))
>>> df = df.withColumn("col",from_json(df.col,"name INT"))

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col.name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: integer (nullable = true)

>>> df.show()
+--------+---+
|col.name|col|
+--------+---+
|       a|[1]|
|       b|[2]|
+--------+---+
```

Here we aim to get values for the nested field `name` of the `struct` field `col` :

```py
>>> df.select(col("col.name")).show()  
+----+
|name|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
+----+
```

Here we aim to get values for the single column `col.name`:

```py
>>> df.select(col("`col.name`")).show()
+--------+
|col.name|
+--------+
|       a|
|       b|
+--------+
```